# Polyline map (left-hand and right-hand attribute)

Tags: qgis, line

I'm working with a land-use map which was converted from polygons to lines, I need to export this map as a shapefile where each feature has the left-hand land-use and right-hand land-use, is there any tool to have both attributes? So far my map only has one attribute per feature.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. It would be useful to provide more information about how the polygon-polyline conversion was performed. If the left/right polygons aren't captured at the time the rings are transformed and split, then there isn't any useful information to provide to the next step.